# Error en logueo con certificado FIEL en SAT

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un logueo por certificado FIEL en el SAT en https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/ pero me retorna un error "Certificado invalido" pero cuando el logueo se hace manual funciona normalmente, este es el codigo que implemente.

```
async solicitud (req: Request, res: Response, next: Next) {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  slowMo: 400,
})
try {
  const certificates = await getInfoBusiness(req.payload.idBusiness)
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://portalcfdi.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/')
  await page.click('button[id="buttonFiel"]')
  await espera(2)
  const [fileCert] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForFileChooser(),
    page.click('button[id="btnCertificate"]')
  ])
  await fileCert.accept([certificate.certPath])
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('input[id="rfc"]').setAttribute('value', certificate.rfc)
  })
  await espera(1)
  const [fileKey] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForFileChooser(),
    page.click('button[id="btnPrivateKey"]')
  ])
  await fileKey.accept([certificate.keyPath])
  await page.type('input[id="privateKeyPassword"]', certificate.password, { delay: 100})
  await page.click('input[id="submit"]')
  await espera(4)
  res.send({ msg: 'Correct' })
  next()
} catch (error) {
  next(error)
} finally {
  await browser.close()
}
```